# Unable to deploy bitbucket repository on the server through capistrano

Tags: git, zend-framework, capistrano, bitbucket

I am trying to deploy my bitbucket repository on my production server but unable to. When I execute push pull from my Git bash everything works but capistrano fails to achieve the same.

```
  set :application, "my_app"
  set :user, "username"
  set :repository,  "ssh://git@bitbucket.org/accountname/repository.git"
  role :web, "www.domain.com"
  set :deploy_to,   "/home/domaincom/domain.com"
  set :use_sudo, false
  set :scm,        :git
  set :branch,     'master'
  set :deploy_via, :copy
  set :copy_cache, true
  set :copy_exclude, %w(.git)


  task :create_symlinks, :roles => :web do
  run "rm #{current_release}/public/.htaccess"
  run "ln -s #{current_release}/shared/.htaccess #{current_release}/public/.htaccess"
  run "ln -s /home/domaincom/libraries/Zend #{current_release}/library/Zend"
  end

  after "deploy:finalize_update", :create_symlinks
```

The error that i get is this on deployment

```
   :No such file or directory  -git  ls-remote            ssh://git@bitbucket.org/accountname/repository.git master (Error::ENOENT)
```

Please help me I am stuck on this for past 4 days. Tried adding deployment key as well. but nothing works

EDit:Also please not that I have neither Git nor Capistrano installed on my production server. I am using capistrano on a windows machine

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the capistrano output a few lines before and after the error?

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need git on the production server?

At least the error message looks like that this is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have `git` installed on the server.

With capistrano you just tell your server(s) what commands to execute, the work then happens on the server(s) itself. And one of the things the server(s) are commanded to do is to use `git` to clone/pull your repo. To achieve that, they obviously need git installed...